# BCrypt updating the library and interations - would it break my login?

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt

I’ve an old legacy application using Spring Security (3.1.0) for the BCrypt implementation.
The hashes have some format like

```
$2a$10$Cas1.FrwwQ3...WqS1i31gHrk12J9YK
```

For the implementation the encoder:

```
PasswordEncoder BCRYPT = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCRYP_ITERATIONS);
```

is used for creating hash (to be stored in database) and for matching.

My questions are:

1. If I simply change the `BCRYP_ITERATIONS` from currently 10 to 18 would this break my login?
   From how I understand BCrypt it would not – as for the matching it would simply use the iteration value that is stored inside the hash itself (`$2a$10$`).
   And for creating new hashes to be stored in database the new value is used.
2. If I’m updating the library to recent implementation that uses new version (`$2b$`) of BCryprt – would this break my login?
   As it somehow changes the method I would say yes – is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading Spring Security shouldn't break your login, because the latest snapshot of Spring Security 5.2 still supports `$2a`, see [`BCryptPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html):

> Implementation of PasswordEncoder that uses the BCrypt strong hashing function. Clients can optionally supply a "version" ($2a, $2b, $2y) and a "strength" (a.k.a. log rounds in BCrypt) and a SecureRandom instance. The larger the strength parameter the more work will have to be done (exponentially) to hash the passwords. The default value is 10.

neither should 18 log rounds break your login, because the latest snapshot of Spring Security 5.2 still supports 4 to 31 log rounds, see [`BCryptPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html#BCryptPasswordEncoder-int-):

> strength - the log rounds to use, between 4 and 31

Answer (score 1):

> 1: if I simply change the BCRYP_ITERATIONS from currently 10 to 18 – would this break my login?
>       From how I understand BCrypt it would not – as for the matching it would simply use the iteration value that is stored inside the hash itself ( $2a$10$). And for creating new hashes to be stored in Database the new value is used.

Yes, you are correct. This will not break your existing password hashes stored and will take the iterations from the hashed password itself not from the value of `BCRYP_ITERATIONS`.

> 2: If I’m updating the library to recent implementation that uses new version ($2b$) of BCryprt – would this break my login?
>       As it somehow changes the method I would say Yes – is this true?

If you change from `$2a$` to `$2b$` it is just a minor version change. This means those are just bug fixes or slight enhancements to safety and performance so it would not break the functionality.

Comment: *This means those are just bug fixes or slight enhancements to safety and performance so it would not break the functionality.* My understanding is, that it would break OP's functionality, that is the reason the version changed, see https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=139320023202696